# ElasticSearch,mongoDB,nodejs for live search

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch

I am using using MongoDB(3.0.3),Elastic Search(1.7.1) , NodeJS.

Actually in our Database we have multiple collections like task , users , jobs , events etc Now we want full text search on Multiple collections in MongoDB but till now MongoDB does not provide that . So we use elastic search for fulltext search from multiple collections .

We want that whatever we insert in MongoDB in these collections jobs,events,users etc is automatically save into Elastic Search index and it is available for searching instantaneously . Is there any npm module which can help me or any other ideas .

After searching on this I found https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb and https://github.com/mongoosastic/mongoosastic

So which is better and easy to use ? or any other solution

Answer (score 1):

Rivers have been deprecated:

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/deprecating-rivers

If you're already using Mongoose then Mongoosastic seems like a good choice. You should check if it's features concerning search fulfill your needs.

Comment: I don't want to create a separate question but what can be use instead of mongoosastic if I use JAVA EE? I spent days to find something instead of richardwilly's mongo-river without any success...

Comment: Why would you search a replacement? Rivers are **deprecated**! There can be **no** replacement!